# What is the Logic behind the User Class? Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, weblogic

I am in Angular 5. 
This is a conceptual question, so let me explain it with an example:

I have a list of users that is only available for logged users. The user list just needs the name and the user ID. And for the user logged, I need tokens for authentications.

So my question is: **Do I have to create 2 users classes?**, one for the user from the login, with all the tokens, and another one without the tokens, and just with the name and the id fields.

Or maybe, can I create just one User class, with the fields for the tokens and that user class, use it for the user list?.

Which one is the best practice?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to have one User class with optional property.

```
class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  token?: string;
}

user1 = { id: 1, name:"User 1", token:"token1"};
user2 = { id: 1, name:"User 1"};
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the solution, thanks a lot! . Can you upvote my question?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you should have 2 classes one representing the AuthUser (for the logged user) and the other for Users (the list of users ). why ? Because in that way I keep my code more clean in term of business logic

Comment: Ummm, okey let me try it.. 

Can you upvote my question?

Answer (score 1):

As each token is supposed to belong to exactly one user there is no separation needed. Just put the token field directly into the user class.

Comment: Okey, that give me an idea, thanks! 
Can you upvote my question?